# ECHOLIFE HG8245c not resetting nor i can access 192.168.1.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, reset

i have GPON router mode number EchoLie hg8245C It was working fine untill i uncheck the option ofenable SSID now neither the wifi is turning on nor i can access the router via lan cable i.e it is not taking me to 192.168.1.1 . ifconfig gives following out out in terminal

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet6 fe80::ee71:6727:7413:430b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether d0:17:c2:17:59:40  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 15709  bytes 10971495 (10.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 58  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 16621  bytes 12300903 (12.3 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

i also tried to rest it via reset button but it is not resetting even tried pressing button for 1 minute

Comment: Can you please give a clearer description of what you did and what happend.
- I guess disabling the SSID means that you disabled WIFI.
- Your client doesn't show an IPv4 ip address. Maybe IPv6 is disabled on the router.
- Regarding IPv4, you won't be able to talk to the router unless you have an IP address in the same subnet, eg. 192.168.1.2. Try to set this IP manually, and then try to connect via cable.
- The headline says you try to connect to 192.168.1.0 (probably not a computer's addresss), while the text says you are trying to connect to 192.168.1.1 (makes more sense).

Comment: Try resetting exactly as suggested..  Router off. turn ON, Press Factory Reset button and hold for at least 15 seconds. Try again and please let us know.

Comment: @BogisW sorry it was a typo. i cant access 192.168.1.1 i just edited my question as well.yes i disabled SSID[wifi]. i have also tried to set IP manually still cant get to router's page.

Comment: @John as i mentioned i have also tried resetting but it do not reset even hold on the button for 1 minute but nothing happens. also tried 30/30/30 reset, no luck. and also tried again for 15 sec on your advice still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

solved. i set my ip,default gateway and subnet manually and tried again.finally was able to access the router page and problem resloved.
actually previously i was trying to set 192.168.1.1 ip address [ as written on back of my router] and it didnt worked today i tries 192.168.100.1 as ip [provided by my isp who provided this router] and it worked like charm.